# What does it mean by using 'source <some env path>' command in linux?

Tags: linux

After creating virtual environment

```
virtualenv env
```

why do we need to fire `source` command ?

```
source env/bin/activate
```

What is the use of source command in general in linux ?

Comment: Have a look at this [source](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do)(sarcasm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

source  : it will read file and execute cmd in file, in current shell environment.

usually it's used to add some environment vars.

for example.

```
> echo $MY_ENV
// nothing 

> cat foo.txt
export MY_ENV=bar
> source foo.txt
// after source, MY_ENV is set in current env

> echo $MY_ENV
bar
```